# PgAdmin - PostgreSQL Can't display correctly long text

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I can't display text data type in **pgAdmin 4 (web client).**

Basically I've developed a spring boot project that store an entity X that have an attribute of type String witch contain some XML.

***Attribut Definition :***

```
@Lob 
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "xml_content")
private String xmlContent;
```

***Generated SQL for that attribute :***

```
xml_content text COLLATE pg_catalog."default";
```

When my object is persisted and I try to check in pgAdmin I have the following output :

[image: pgAdmin QueryTool Output]

I can't understand why the column **xml_content** has that value instead of a text.
Does PostgreSQL store those texts in other tables ?

BTW this is the first time working with PostgreSQL so I don't have much knowledge about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing `@Lob`? E.g. specifying `@Column(name = "xml_content", columnDefinition = "text")` instead?

Comment: It works I can read the XML now, Thanks for the help

Comment: It seems Hibernate created that columns as a `large object` rather than `xml`